# Column-width container not extending to all colums

Tags: jquery, html, css, column-width

Having a bit of an issue getting content with column-width to display properly. **[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/h53wbrsb/).**

What needs to happen is for the gray background to extend to all, not just the first column. The issue comes from using "`width:300px;`" on "`.wrapper`", but if that's removed then the columns won't be of equal width/height and get all messy when browser is resized. Any tips?

Many thanks!

```
.wrapper {
    width:300px;
    background:#ccc;
}
.wrapper p {
    height:300px;

    -webkit-column-width:300px;
    -moz-column-width:300px;
    column-width:300px;
}
```

Comment: Is this the result you are looking for?, all I did was remove the width from the wrapper (as its the container), and add it to the p element http://jsfiddle.net/h53wbrsb/1/

Comment: Just altering a bit to give column gaps http://jsfiddle.net/hpsxjk8f/

Comment: Anand Gangadhara, the columns in your fiddle are no longer equal width/height. As in, they change when the browser is resized and don't keep the set height.

Comment: larssy, the background really needs to extend to the columns and no further, like this: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/159548794/2col-wrap.jpg

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure if this is what you are looking for, as the topic is somewhat unclear for me.

The grey background is 300 pixels because you set the background on the wrapper that is 300 pixels. In order to get it over the entire width, all we'll need to do is to remove the width from the wrapper and add it to the p element.

```
.wrapper {
    background:#ccc;
}
.wrapper p {
    width: 300px;
    height:300px;

    -webkit-column-width:300px;
    -moz-column-width:300px;
    column-width:300px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/h53wbrsb/1/

Comment: The background really needs to extend to the columns and no further, like this: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/159548794/2col-wrap.jpg

Comment: Also, when resized, this happens: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/159548794/resize.jpg

Comment: I personally think that the Columns is still an experimental CSS3 feature. So far I've noticed the following: [1] Defining a width deletes shared backgrounds. [2] Using columns-width may disable the columns property when resized. [3] Columns-count may be required to properly show, resizeable columsn. Working examle: http://jsfiddle.net/h53wbrsb/5/

Comment: I hear ya about the experimental thing. Browsers are certainly not very encouraging when it comes to columns or horizontal designs, unless you know exactly how much text, images etc you have that. So it works for static pages but for themes and such it's a real pain. I just wish it wasn't :)

Comment: Exactly, therefore I think you shouldn't be using columns the way you are trying to. However, if you'd still like to continue like this, i'd suggest this page: https://css-tricks.com/guide-responsive-friendly-css-columns/ just looked it up, and seems to be explaining things nicely.